# Getting the necessary permissions to write to a usb flash drive with python on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, usb

I've got a program that allows a user to save data as a .txt file to a set filepath on a raspberry pi. I'm running the script on a headless Ubuntu server and it works totally fine on any of the normal directories but gives me `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: *filepath to usb*` whenever I try to write to my usb drive. Boiled down the code looks like this:

```
if overwrite:
    file = open(filepath, 'w')
else:
    file = open(filepath +'/CAN_Data.txt','w')


while save_status:
    msg = raw_data_queue.get()
    file.write(msg + '\n')
    if msg == 'END': #sent when stop save pressed
        file.close()
        save_status = False
        break
```

When a user clicks the start save button, save_status becomes True and the program gets messages from a queue and then pastes them either into an existing txt file or a new one depending on the override status stated by the user. I've already tried editing permissions to the file using `sudo chmod 777 /dev/sda1` and `sudo chmod 777 /media/usb0` <- the directory I mounted the flash drive to. However, none of these have worked and I still get the same error when running my code.

Comment: Would it work to run the program with sudo perms? Like `sudo python main.py`?

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of this earlier. It worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the program with sudo perms like `sudo python3 main.py` and the issue resolved itself.